# Using addProgressListener and onStatusChange to obtain DNS lookup times for pages

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying to add functionality to a firefox extension to time how long it takes a webpage to perform DNS lookup. Looking at Firebug, I figured it's possible to do so by adding a web progress listener to the browser object and listening for events.

First I register an event listener when a page is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { myObj.onLoad(e); }, false);
```

Inside myObj.onLoad() I register my web progress listener as such:

```
 gBrowser.addProgressListener(this, Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_ALL);
```

Finally I implement 'onStatusChange' inside myObj, along with QueryInterface and others:

```
onStatusChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage) {
    this.logInfo("onStatusChange: " + aMessage + ". Time = " + (new Date().getTime()));
}
```

However, when onStatusChange is called, aStatus is always 0 even though aMessage displays the correct event. I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Any ideas why??

Also it seems that onStatusChange with status of 'Ci.nsISocketTransport.STATUS_RESOLVING' is only being called on some components, without being called for others, even though they may have a different domain name that needs to be translated and the DNS has not been cached. Need help plz!

Comment: I'm just wandering, you're adding your method on load event of the page? That's called when page has finished loading, am I missing something?

Comment: onLoad should get called when the window is done loading, e.g. before the request for the web page is sent out

Comment: So that is onload in chrome window?

Comment: From mozilla documentation, I understand so. At least I know I'm getting DNS Lookup times for _some_ components but the fact that aStatus is always 0 still leaves me perplexed

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a progress listener to the tabbed browser you only get a filtered view of progress events. You might find that you need to attach your progress listener to the inner browser instead. (If you want to watch multiple tabs/windows you might find it better to attach your progress listener to the window itself, or, for a service, to the root document loader.)

Comment: How can I attach a progress listener to a window? Also, what is the "root document loader"?

Comment: @SergiuToarca The root document loader is the component `@mozilla.org;docloader;1` which receives all progress events in the browser. To attach a progress listener to a window you need its nsIWebProgress object; you can use the webProgress property on the containing browser element or you can call getInterface on the window (you may have to get the nsIDocShell first).